# Can I get a replay from a saved game?

Tags: warcraft-3-the-frozen-throne, warcraft-3

Can I get a replay in Warcraft 3: The Frozen Throne from a saved game? If so, how?

Answer (score 2):

Usually no,its a long shot but you could try this if you want to be sure. 
Depending on what are you trying to load you can try loading the game and finishing it then there might be option to save a replay automatically.

(if you played multiplayer,the replay after the point where it was saved will be retarded since you will be the only one left to finish it,but you can use the rest as video material)

If you have version greater than 1.24e in your options menu>gameplay you can turn on automatic save replay,and after finishing the loaded game you can check replays if it worked check in your warcraft 3 directory in replays folder,there it could be saved as "lastsavedreplay" and not recognized by w3.

Answer (score 1):

After the end of the game, if you save the replay，you can find it in this path:

*/warcraft3/replay/*

you can also set Auto-save replay which will save in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to extract the information necessary to make a Replay?
Not via any Warcraft 3 interface.

WC3 will not save replays, nor offer the chance to do so, for any missions initiated by any of these choices in the Single Player menu:

- Campaign
- Load Saved Game
- Custom Campaign